# Replace Django Button data-url With DRF Equivalent

Tags: python, ajax, django, datatables, django-rest-framework

I have a DataTable that includes the following column definition to add a button to each row:

```
"columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": 11,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-activity' data-url='https://server/platform/activities/104/update/'></button>"
            } ],
```

It works, except the number 104 is a hard coded id. The plain Django version looks like this:

```
{% for activity in activities %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ activity.id }}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-activity"
              data-url="{% url 'activity_update' activity.id %}">
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`activity_update` is a URL name for this URL:

```
url(r'^platform/activities/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.activity_update, name='activity_update')
```

If I use the plain Django version in the DRF version, I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'activity_update' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['platform/activities/(?P<pk>\\d+)/update/$']
```

Obviously `activity.id` is not defined in the DRF view, because the data is flowing in via a JSON endpoint. Therefore, I need to figure out how to assign the id from the DataTable row to the `data-url` attribute.

I tried doing this...

```
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 11,
     "data": null,
     "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return "<button type='button' aria-label='update' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-activity' data-url='https://server/platform/activities/'" + row.id + "'/update/'></button>";
        },
```

...but this results in the request just going to `https://server/platform/activities/` and ignoring the rest of `data-url`. When I print `row.id` to the console, it gives me the correct id for each row visible in the DataTable.

How would I mimic the plain Django version of the button so that data-url properly returns the hard coded URL for each row of the DataTable?